# ResNet output dimensions

Tags: neural-networks

So I am currently going over the [ResNet](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/He_Deep_Residual_Learning_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) paper and trying to understand the output dimensions of each of the layer, and it seems that I am already stuck on the first layer and its output dimension.

If I understand correctly, the size of output of a particular layer can be calculated as **(ORIGINAL_SIZE - FILTER_SIZE) / STRIDE + 1**

In the plain example of the ResNet, presented below on the right hand side, they claim they use 224x224 image. Therefore, when I calculate the output dimension of the 7x7 convolution with stride 2, I get

(224 - 7) / 2 + 1 = 109.5, so I round it 110.

However, in the paper they claim that their output size is 112. How would that be possible?

[image: ResNet plain 34-layer]

Comment: 112=224/2 seems to be the correct calculation.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so where is the 7x7 convolution?

Comment: It's probably an implementation detail. Maybe they apply the convolution even outside the boundary of the actual image. It's not a big deal.

Comment: I am asking as I am trying to understand what happens when remaining size is 1,  but there is still a convolution layer with filter size greater than the actual width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an official github [repository](https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/blob/master/prototxt/ResNet-50-deploy.prototxt), and they use a padding of size 3, and therefore the output 112.